# Biblatex: How to get rid of reference number within a single bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I have the following LaTeX code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{bestpapergyro}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{bestpaperstark}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{Gyro2012,
        author = {Gearloose, Gyro},
        title = {1st paper},
        category = bestpapergyro,
    }
    @misc{Gyro2013,
        author = {Gearloose, Gyro},
        title = {2nd paper},
    }
    @misc{Stark2012,
        author = {Stark, Anthony Edward},
        title = {3rd paper},
    }
    @misc{Stark2013,
        author = {Stark, Anthony Edward},
        title = {4th paper},
        category = bestpaperstark,
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\addtocategory{bestpapergyro}{Gyro2012}
\addtocategory{bestpaperstark}{Stark2013}

\noindent Favorite paper by Gyro Gearloose:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \printbibliography[heading=none,category=bestpapergyro]
\end{itemize}

\noindent Favorite paper by Anthony Stark:
\begin{itemize}
    \item \printbibliography[heading=none,category=bestpaperstark]
\end{itemize}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

that results in the following output

```
Favorite paper by Gyro Gearloose:
• [1] Gyro Gearloose. 1st paper.

Favorite paper by Anthony Stark:
• [4] Anthony Edward Stark. 4th paper.

References
[1] Gyro Gearloose. 1st paper.
[2] Gyro Gearloose. 2nd paper.
[3] Anthony Edward Stark. 3rd paper.
[4] Anthony Edward Stark. 4th paper.
```

Basically, I want to show a list of best papers for each author in a separate itemization.
Currently, I do this by creating a best paper category for each author and then print the bibliography for these categories.

I have two Questions:
 1. How can I get rid of the reference numbers within the itemizations (without changing the style of the bibliography at the end)?
 2. Is there an easier way to print the bibliography for a single entry than specifying an own category?

Comment: Your second issue depends on the requirements. You have the possibility to use `defbibcheck`.

Comment: With regard to question 2, I'd simpy use `\fullcite`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would define a new bibliography environment and a new heading. So yo have a better control about the output

1. The new bibliography environment based on `itemize`

   ```
   \defbibenvironment{favoritebib}
     {\itemize}
     {\enditemize}
     {\item}
   ```
2. The new title uses `subsubsection*`:

   ```
   \defbibheading{favoritebib}[\refname]{%
     \subsubsection*{Favorite paper by~#1:}}
   ```
3. The output is done by `printbibliography` with some options:

   ```
   \printbibliography[heading=favoritebib,title=Gyro Gearloose,category=bestpapergyro,env=favoritebib]
   ```

Here a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{bestpapergyro}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{bestpaperstark}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{Gyro2012,
        author = {Gearloose, Gyro},
        title = {1st paper},
        category = bestpapergyro,
    }
    @misc{Gyro2013,
        author = {Gearloose, Gyro},
        title = {2nd paper},
    }
    @misc{Stark2012,
        author = {Stark, Anthony Edward},
        title = {3rd paper},
    }
    @misc{Stark2013,
        author = {Stark, Anthony Edward},
        title = {4th paper},
        category = bestpaperstark,
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibenvironment{favoritebib}
  {\itemize}
  {\enditemize}
  {\item}
\defbibheading{favoritebib}[\refname]{%
    \subsubsection*{Favorite paper by~#1:}}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\addtocategory{bestpapergyro}{Gyro2012,Gyro2013}
\addtocategory{bestpaperstark}{Stark2013}


\printbibliography[heading=favoritebib,title=Gyro Gearloose,category=bestpapergyro,env=favoritebib]

\printbibliography[heading=favoritebib,title=Anthony Stark,category=bestpaperstark,env=favoritebib]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

As pointed out by lockstep you can use `\fullcite` for a single author reference. Related to the example above:

```
\subsubsection*{Favorite paper by Anthony Stark:}
\begin{itemize}
 \item \fullcite{Stark2012}
\end{itemize}
```

Of course this can be put inside a new macro:

```
\newrobustcmd*\citefavorite[2]{%
\subsubsection*{Favorite paper by~#1:}
\begin{itemize}
 \item \fullcite{#2}
\end{itemize}%
}
```

Now you can use `\citefavorite{<Name of Author>}{<cite key>}`

Comment: +1 for using the `env` key which I had overlooked.

Comment: `\fullcite` is definitely what I was looking for. Thank you both for your help.